# CS1703: In Xamarin.Droid, should I use the .Net Standard windowsruntime.dll located in Mono.Framework, or System.Runtime?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mono, .net-standard, csc

I'm trying to build [this Android Xamarin project](https://github.com/RobGibbens/ResilientServices), and am getting the compile time error:

```
./ResilientServices/ResilientServices.Droid/CSC: 
  Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported:

./ResilientServices/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'
 and  
./Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. 

 Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (ResilientServices.Droid)
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue,  did you resolve it?

Comment: @JDibble if many projects exist, make sure dll versions are the same among each one. Dependencies matter

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this just this week.  No idea what change caused it.

What worked for me was commenting out the HintPath in the .csproj Reference:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime">
    <!--HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath-->
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336919/xamarin-android-will-not-compile-multiple-assemblies-with-equivalent-identity-h), btw.