# Xamarin Android will not compile: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

You can see the error below.

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`

One version is installed in my project's packages, and another one is needed for the Mono framework. I feel like the Mono Framework should probably be the one that wins. This error does not happen on my iOS builds.

How would I go about telling Visual Studio Community (Mac) not to reference the offending dll?

```
/myproject/path/MyApp.Droid/CSC: 
Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 
'/myproject/path/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll' and 
'/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. 
Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (MyApp.Droid)
```

Comment: Upgrading from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` 4.0.1 to 4.3.0 makes this build error go away. How would I avoid this behavior in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this just this week.  No idea what change caused it.

What worked for me was commenting out the HintPath in the .csproj Reference:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime">
    <!--HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath-->
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862676/cs1703-in-xamarin-droid-should-i-use-the-net-standard-windowsruntime-dll-loca), btw.